# Javascript : Add Key & Value at specific index in array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of Object like this.

```js
let arr =  [{name:"abc",age:26},{name:"xyz",age:23},{name:"pqr",age:10}]

let newVal  = arr.map(function(el) {

                

                if(el.age > 25){
                    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
                    o.gender = 'male';
                    return o;

                }
              })

              console.log("New Val : " , newVal)
```

I would like to add {gender:'male'} to object where age is > 25

It says undefined to other objects.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value if the object doesn't match the condition. Since you haven't retrned anything from from inside map if the condition is not fulfilled, you get undefined for the other objects

```js
let arr = [{
  name: "abc",
  age: 26
}, {
  name: "xyz",
  age: 23
}, {
  name: "pqr",
  age: 10
}]

let newVal = arr.map(function(el) {
  if (el.age > 25) {
    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
    o.gender = 'male';
    return o;

  }
  return el; // return value here
})

console.log("New Val : ", newVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

issue with your code is already solved in other answer by Shubham, ie when if clause is not executed you are not returning anything.

but i think forEach might be cleaner here

if you want to keep the original array you can copy it using `copyArr = [...arr]`

```js
let arr =  [{name:"abc",age:26},{name:"xyz",age:23},{name:"pqr",age:10}]
arr.forEach(function(el) {
                if(el.age > 25)
                    el.gender = 'male';
              })

console.log("New Val : " , arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's missing the return statement when the condition is false.

You can do this in one line using an arrow function as follow:

```js
let arr =  [{name:"abc",age:26},{name:"xyz",age:23},{name:"pqr",age:10}],
    newVal = arr.map((el) => Object.assign({}, el, el.age > 25 ? {gender: "male"} : {}));

console.log("New Val:", newVal);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a new array with `map`. Inside, you need to take either an copy of the object with a new property or the original object.

```js
let array =  [{ name: "abc", age: 26 }, { name: "xyz", age: 23 }, { name: "pqr", age: 10 }],
    result = array.map(object => object.age > 25 
        ? { ... object, gender: 'male' }
        : object
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```